# Stuck trying to model a Turban using cloth simulation

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I've been wanting to model this turban:

[image: Turban on top of head]

I'm bad at sculpting and so to avoid it here's what I tried:

Started with a circle, extruded and scaled it a couple of times, then applied a subdiv, shrinkwrap and solidy modifiers to get this shape:
[image: Circle extruded with a shrinkwrap modifier]

Then I'm running cloth sim using a pinning group, with weights like so:

[image: Weights used]

But results are clunky and all over the place. Any Ideas I might try or different parameters that I need to mess with to get the desired results?

Comment: hello, why not use sculpt instead?

Comment: I've been trying for a week to use sculpt it but I can't for the life of me get the folds right. Do you think my best shot is to sculpt it instead of using simulations ?

Comment: Hi. First, I think you should get a better reference on a turban. 
Investing some time in learning how to sculpt would probably save you a lot of time even with this single part.
If you find it interesting to solve this with cloth simulation, you should try to brake it up in as many prices as you can and do one layer at a time.

Comment: @InventedTech  you first need to roughly model a low-poly shape, then switch to Sculpt mode and use brushes like Draw, Crease... Like Jackdaw says, maybe use several reference images to see how it looks like

Comment: I'll try just that! Thanks guys, I'll switch to sculpting again and keep at it

Answer (score 0):

Using a curve might work.

Make the curve curve around the head, in the shape you want and give it a bevel in its settings or use another curve as bevel.